# Join two data frames using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join

I would like to join two data frames. Given I have two data frames (df1 and df2):

df1:

```
        15/06/2020  16/06/2020
Apples  20          19
Bananas 17          20
Oranges 12          15
Carrots 25          5
```

df2:

```
        17/06/2020
Apples  22
Bananas 14
Oranges 16
Pears   7
Lettuce 19
Tomato  11
```

How do I create df3?

df3:

```
        15/06/2020  16/06/2020  17/06/2020
Apples  20          19          22
Bananas 17          20          14
Oranges 12          15          16
Carrots 25          5           
Pears                           7
Lettuce                         19
Tomato                          11
```

Comment: `df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])`?

Comment: `pd.concat([df1,df2],sort=True)
`

Comment: That's not a join, but an append or concatenation. Use the methods given by the other comments.